# Shell script for copying the specific file from csv to another directory with same folder hierarchy structure

Tags: bash, shell, csv, copy

I have a list of files to copy from smb server to my centos7 hard drive from csv

**missing.csv**

```
Filepath
./2019_06_27_094411_Season_5/Locked_Approved/Master_JPG/501_00001.jpg
./2019_06_27_094411_Season_5/Locked_Approved/Master_JPG/501_00002.jpg
./2019_06_27_094411_Season_5/Locked_Approved/Master_JPG/501_00003.jpg
./2019_06_27_094411_Season_5/Locked_Approved/Master_JPG/501_00004.jpg
./2019_06_27_094411_Season_5/Locked_Approved/Master_JPG/501_00005.jpg
./2019_06_27_094411_Season_5/Locked_Approved/Master_JPG/501_00006.jpg
./2019_06_27_094411_Season_5/Locked_Approved/Master_JPG/501_00007.jpg
```

Now i need to copy the files from the csv list (i.e)`filepath column` and past it in my local drive with the same directory structure.

I have tried the following script and able to copy only the files, i need the file same as source directory structure.
- I have installed and mounted the smbclient in my centos machine

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

while read path; do
  cp -v "$path" "$1"
done
```

**CMD:** `./script.sh /home/test1 < missing.csv`

Comment: This might help: [Bash: Copy named files recursively, preserving folder structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1650164/3776858)

Answer (score 0):

For simple cases (no spaces/special characters in file names, ...), possible to combine the '--parents' (sugested by cyrus above) with the full list of files. Potentially using xargs to support large number of files

```
cp --parents -t "$path" $(cat)
# Using xargs to allow larger number of files
xargs cp --parents -t "$path"
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if missing.csv contains spaces, this does well.

script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
dest="${1}"
while read l
do
    f="${dest}/${l}"
    d=$(dirname "${f}")
    mkdir -p "${d}"
    cp "${l}" "${f}"                                                            
done
```

```
$ cat missing.csv 
./2019 06 27 094411 Season 5/Locked Approved/Master JPG/501 00001.jpg
./2019 06 27 094411 Season 5/Locked Approved/Master JPG/501 00002.jpg
./2019 06 27 094411 Season 5/Locked Approved/Master JPG/501 00003.jpg
./2019 06 27 094411 Season 5/Locked Approved/Master JPG/501 00004.jpg
./2019 06 27 094411 Season 5/Locked Approved/Master JPG/501 00005.jpg
./2019 06 27 094411 Season 5/Locked Approved/Master JPG/501 00006.jpg
./2019 06 27 094411 Season 5/Locked Approved/Master JPG/501 00007.jpg
```

```
$ ./script.sh ./dest < missing.csv
```

```
$ find dest -type f
dest/2019 06 27 094411 Season 5/Locked Approved/Master JPG/501 00007.jpg
dest/2019 06 27 094411 Season 5/Locked Approved/Master JPG/501 00006.jpg
dest/2019 06 27 094411 Season 5/Locked Approved/Master JPG/501 00004.jpg
dest/2019 06 27 094411 Season 5/Locked Approved/Master JPG/501 00005.jpg
dest/2019 06 27 094411 Season 5/Locked Approved/Master JPG/501 00001.jpg
dest/2019 06 27 094411 Season 5/Locked Approved/Master JPG/501 00002.jpg
dest/2019 06 27 094411 Season 5/Locked Approved/Master JPG/501 00003.jpg
```