# Bash - Copy files iteratively

Tags: bash, loops

I want to copy a list of files, called `dti_fin_fa`, from one folder to another.

These files are scattered in different folders.

```
   Controls

   └───C01
   │   └───difusion 
   │       └───Deterministic
   │             └───dti_fin_fa.nii
   └───C02
   │   └───difusion 
   │       └───Deterministic
   │             └───dti_fin_fa.nii
   └───C03
   │   └───difusion 
   │       └───Deterministic
   │             └───dti_fin_fa.nii
```

I want to select and copy all the `dti_fin_fa`, keeping the folder structure, so, in my new directory, I would have the folder distribution just seen above. The problem is that in this folders, (`deterministic`, `difusion`, etc), there are lots of other files I don´t want to copy, so I can´t just copy the main folder (`C01` etc)

This is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR="/media/Batty/Analysis"; cd "$DIR" || exit
for group in Controls; do
    for folder in $group/*; do
        for dti in $folder/difussion/Deterministic/dti_fin_fa.nii; do
        echo $dti
        cp $dti /media/Roy/Analysis/Controls/ --verbose
        done;
    done;
done;
```

The problem is that this code copies each of the `dti_fin_fa.nii` images into `/media/Roy/Analysis/Controls/`, hence keeping just the last one, instead of creating all the other subfolders.

Could something like this work?

`cp $folder/difusion/Deterministic/$dti /media/Roy/Analysis/Patients/ --verbose`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash: Copy named files recursively, preserving folder structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650164/bash-copy-named-files-recursively-preserving-folder-structure)

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through each control, make the equivalent directory and copy only the file you want:

```sh
for group in "Control"/* "Patients"/*; do
  orig="$group/difusion/Deterministic"
  dest="/media/Roy/Analysis/Controls/$(dirname group)/$orig" 
  mkdir -p "$dest"
  cp "$orig/dti_fin_fa.nii" "$dest/" 
done
```

I suppose you execute this from the `DIR` directory of your example. So here `orig` is the relative path to the image folder, `dest` is the absolute path to your destination directory, including the preserved original folder structure. `mkdir -p` ensures that such end directory exists and finally the image is copied.

Comment: Thanks @Miguel, but I don´t understand this line `dest="/media/Roy/Analysis/Controls/$group/$dir"` .  What is that `$dir` doing? If  I `echo $dest`, this is what I get `/media/Roy/Analysis/Controls/Controls/*/`. Shouldn´t it be just one `Control`.

Comment: there are errors in your code, as for example should be `"Controls"/*` and `"Patients"/*`, and $dir is reference but not assigned

Comment: OK, check it now, I corrected the errors (you should edit your question to mention the Patients folder) and added some explanations.