# Bash does not list all files with ls

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i have a bash code, and i need list the files of a path and save in a file

```
processVerification(){
    ls $1 > testFiles
}
```

and in the folder i have the files

```
transaction-2012-01-20.csv
transaction-2012-01-21.csv
transaction-2012-01-22.csv
transaction-2012-01-23.csv
transaction-2012-01-24.csv
transaction-2013-01-24.csv
transaction-2013-02-24.csv
```

when i call processVerification
    folder=/home/folder/transactions-2012*
    command="cat" 
    processVerification $folder $command

```
$ cat testFiles
```

I have Only transaction-2012-01-20.csv and i need all files.

But i need only the transactions of 2012 and i create processVerification because i need pass 50 distinct folders and the command is because in some folders i have .csv and in others i have .csv.bz2 and in others i have .csv.gz

and the files in each folder are distinct

Comment: THe `*` expansion happens _before_ it comes to your function call. You could do a `processVerification "/home/folder/transactions-2012*"` preserving the `*` untill later.

Comment: I've voted to close this question because the asker keeps changing it. @Benito, please try to formulate your question before asking.

Answer (score 4):

You edited your post, and now the error makes sense.  When you call processVerification like this:

```
processVerification /home/folder/transactions-2012*
```

That passes all of the transactions-2012* files to processVerification(), but in that function you only look at the first argument.  Try this instead to look at all args:

```
processVerification(){
    ls "$@" > testFiles
}
```

Comment: For whitespace-safety, use `"$@"`

Comment: @glennjackman, good catch. I have updated my answer. I typically use zsh, which seems to handle whitespace in $@ just fine without the quotes.

Comment: @BenitoCamelas, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: i call processVerification $folder $command and say me ls: cat: No such file or directory

Comment: because i pass 2 parameters the folder and the command to read

Comment: @MarkkuK. Benito means that as he is giving the command (`cat`, which isn't shown in the function but _is_ shown in the function call), will be an argument to `ls`.

Comment: You keep updating your question, it makes it difficult to give a good answer.  Where is the "cat" argument supposed to be used in processVerification()?

Comment: Trying to read between the lines, maybe you want this: `command=cat processVerification /home/folder/transactions-2012*`. Then if you want to run "cat" on testFiles, add this line to processVerification(): `$command testFiles`

Comment: Yes i need use cat or zcat or bzcat depend of the folder, because in some folder i have compress the files and in others not

Comment: Note that if you need _all argument but the last_, there's a [question here that deals with that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215538/bash-extract-parameters-before-last-parameter-in), but preventing `*` expansion untill later seems equally workable.

Comment: If you remove "command=cat" from the argument list, then it won't be a problem. Putting "command=cat" in front of the function call puts that variable "command" into the environment of that function call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ls -1` and pipe it to `grep`.

```
processVerification() {
    ls -1 | grep 'transaction-2012' > testFiles
}
```

Your problem is that you are calling processVerification with the **wrong argument.** You should be doing:

`processVerification /home/folder/`

Not:

`processVerification /home/folder/transactions-2012*`

Comment: Could be pertinent to use the `--maxdepth` option to limit recursivity.

Comment: Not works with ls -1 $1.  I have Only transaction-2012-01-20.csv

Comment: I believe that the problem is the (*) transactions-2012*

Comment: You are calling `processVerification` with the wrong argument, see my edit.

Comment: But i need only the transactions of 2012 and i create processVerification because i need pass 50  distinct folders

Comment: Then you should filter the `ls -1` with `grep 'transaction-2012'`. Edited my post to reflect this.

Comment: But  i create  processVerification because i need pass 50 distinct folders and the files in each folder are distinct

Comment: in some folders calls transactions in other calls hightfile-2012-01-09