# How to print multiple lines as field?

Tags: perl, awk

My data as following:

```
P04637 1A1U 1AIE 1C26 1DT7 1GZH 1H26 1HS5 1JSP 1KZY 1MA3 1OLG 1OLH 1PES 1PET 1SAE 1SAF 1SAK 1SAL 1TSR 1TUP 1UOL 1XQH 1YC5 1YCQ
```

But I want as following:

```
P04637 1A1U
P04637 1C26
P04637 1AIE
P04637 1DT7
P04637 1XQH
P04637 1MA3
P04637 1PES
P04637 1SAE
```

Comment: Perl or Awk.. which one?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? StackOverflow is not a "write my code for me" service.

Comment: @DaveCross - I can't understand the up votes for this... No effort made and an initially incomprehensible non-question

Comment: how to export column 2? Seems they are not in original order.

Comment: @ceving: You should upvote questions if they are *well-phrased* and likely to be *highly relevant* to other users. Upvoting because a question gave you an entertaining puzzle breaks the system.

Comment: That is a very poor rule of thumb for posting on Stack Overflow, or any social site for that matter. Moderators have exist because people like you get entertainment from being destructive. Please stop it.

Comment: @ceving: If you mouse over the upvote message then its purpose is clear. *"This question shows reseach effort; it is useful and clear"*. Not *"I like this question cos I had fun with it"*.

Comment: @Borodin Having fun soliloquizing?

Answer (score 4):

This prints the first field and then every subsequent field until end of the line.

```
$ awk '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $1,$i}' file                                 
P04637 1A1U
P04637 1AIE
P04637 1C26
P04637 1DT7
P04637 1GZH
P04637 1H26
P04637 1HS5
P04637 1JSP
P04637 1KZY
P04637 1MA3
P04637 1OLG
P04637 1OLH
P04637 1PES
P04637 1PET
P04637 1SAE
P04637 1SAF
P04637 1SAK
P04637 1SAL
P04637 1TSR
P04637 1TUP
P04637 1UOL
P04637 1XQH
P04637 1YC5
P04637 1YCQ
```

---

To get exactly what OP request, no more, no less:

```
awk '{print $1,$2 RS $1,$4 RS $1,$3 RS $1,$5 RS $1,$23 RS $1,$11 RS $1,$14 RS $1,$16}' file
P04637 1A1U
P04637 1C26
P04637 1AIE
P04637 1DT7
P04637 1XQH
P04637 1MA3
P04637 1PES
P04637 1SAE
```

Comment: classic solution.. +1

Comment: Hi, all, just realize the original question is asking to export randomly, see my solution. :-)

Comment: How can you tell that form the OPs text.  He may have written it wrong. All line is not listed in output request, so he may only need some.  Than all solution here would be wrong.

Comment: @BMW Se my updated post.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach with awk:

```
awk 'NR==1 {a=$1; next} {print a,$1}' RS=" " file
```

By setting `RS=" "` we define the line separator as space. This way, we will fetch every time a different record.

`NR==1` means while reading the first record. There, we store the first value. From that point, we keep writing the saved value + current one.

It returns:

```
P04637 1A1U
P04637 1AIE
P04637 1C26
P04637 1DT7
P04637 1GZH
P04637 1H26
P04637 1HS5
P04637 1JSP
P04637 1KZY
P04637 1MA3
P04637 1OLG
P04637 1OLH
P04637 1PES
P04637 1PET
P04637 1SAE
P04637 1SAF
P04637 1SAK
P04637 1SAL
P04637 1TSR
P04637 1TUP
P04637 1UOL
P04637 1XQH
P04637 1YC5
P04637 1YCQ
```

Comment: nice one +1. I wrote one with setting `OFS`, but leave an empty line. this is better.

Comment: Hi, all, just realize the original question is asking to export randomly, see my solution. :-)

Comment: Well @BMW I wouldn't say randomly. I guess the sample output is just that, a sample, to have the idea. Some clarification from the author could help.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -lane '$v=shift @F; print "$v $_" for @F' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -lane 'print "$F[0] $_" for(@F[1..$#F])'
```

Answer (score 1):

Neither Perl nor Awk is required for this job. Bash is enough:

```
{ IFS=' ' read -r -a A ; for I in ${A[@]:1} ; do echo ${A[0]} $I ; done ; } <<<'P04637 1A1U 1AIE 1C26 1DT7 1GZH 1H26 1HS5 1JSP 1KZY 1MA3 1OLG 1OLH 1PES 1PET 1SAE 1SAF 1SAK 1SAL 1TSR 1TUP 1UOL 1XQH 1YC5 1YCQ'
P04637 1A1U
P04637 1AIE
P04637 1C26
...
```

All you need is already here:

- [Bash: Read tab-separated file line into array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736202/bash-read-file-line-into-array/9736732#9736732)
- [Extract parameters before last parameter in "$@"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215538/bash-extract-parameters-before-last-parameter-in/1215592#1215592)

Answer (score 0):

As a perl script:

```
use warnings;
use strict; 

open my $input, '<', 'in.txt' or die "$!";

while (<$input>){
    my @split = split;
    my $spacer = shift @split;
    print "$spacer $_\n" foreach @split;
}
```

Prints:

```
P04637 1A1U
P04637 1AIE
P04637 1C26
P04637 1DT7
P04637 1GZH ...
```

Comment: He does not asked for tabulators.

Comment: @ceving - he doesn't really ask for anything.

Answer (score 0):

Just realize the original question is asking to export randomly

```
awk 'BEGIN{srand($RANDOM)}
{ split($0,a,FS);
  for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) 
     { while (1) 
         {  s=int(rand()*(NF-1)+2)
            if (a[s]!="") {print $1,a[s];delete a[s];break}
         }
     }
}' file
```

result

```
P04637 1C26
P04637 1H26
P04637 1DT7
P04637 1HS5
P04637 1AIE
P04637 1GZH
P04637 1A1U
```

Comment: For random order `awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)print $1,$i}' file | sort -R`

Comment: Why do you use the number `14`? And `$RANDOM` will be equal to the empty string `""` I think..

Comment: you are right, I have updated to NF-1. I did a test on 14 items before

Comment: this forum is interesting with bad attitude， people gave wrong answer, get votes, who challenge them but got vote down. This is still a free place, and I will keep challenge them without fear.